# Models and mesh start distorting and wobbling - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple space simulator project and the models and the mesh start wobbling and distorting after certain speeds. The code has no errors, so I will give you a 
[gameplay video.](https://download.darkveneno.pt/download/video_bug.mp4)
As you can see in the gameplay video, even simple cylinders get distorted.
Then, I got an interesting 
[bug/error.](https://answers.unity.com/storage/attachments/150245-adfasdfadfasdfadfasdf.png)
Is there a solution to said problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you’re not too far away from the origin of the scene. Things get less precise the further away you go from the origin, and it’s to do with floating point precision.

Comment: Thank you. But since the theme of this is a space sim with long distances, how do I make it always precise?

Comment: @DarkVeneno You will have to "recenter" periodically. You can't just magically say "use more precision please" because the underlying engine uses `float` and what you're seeing is the result of *floating point precision* (or rather, what happens when the exponent goes up several notches and you no longer have precision at small decimal values)

Comment: @Draco18s Thank you. I discovered a script that redirects you to the center of the scene after some discance covered.